# Sharepoint API REST not valid expression when filtering

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

I would filter results to get only pdf documents.

I make a search on all sharepoint site with this link

```
https://server/sites/section/sections2/_api/search/query?querytext=%274AAN81471%27
```

I get all results which are pdf files + parent directories.
Now I try to add a filter to only get paths that contains ".pdf" string to only get pdf documents. So after reading [docs](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35796.sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-for-selecting-filtering-sorting-and-pagination-in-sharepoint-list.aspx) I tried this:

```
https://server/sites/section/sections2/_api/search/query?querytext=%274AAN81471%27$filter=path%20substringof%20%27pdf%27
```

I get this error :

```
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
  The expression "'4AAN81471'$filter=path substringof 'pdf'" is not valid.
</m:message>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter them right inside `queryText` itself.

Modify your endpoint as mentioned below. FileExtension is on ootb managed property available in SharePoint. Here, space acts as `AND` filter in KQL:

```
https://server/sites/section/sections2/_api/search/query?querytext='4AAN81471 FileExtension:pdf'
```

Comment: hey @infodev , any luck ? Did you try the above REST API ?